# Why do we need to use the "transpose" of a transformed matrix? (direct3D11)

Tags: c++, matrix, direct3d11

I have read the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) and also read the [Programmers guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415571.aspx) articles, but I can't seem to put my head around the purpose of transposing a matrix once it has been "transformed"

I mean, I understand what the transpose of a matrix is. I just don't understand why we need to actually take the transpose.

Take this code snippet for example..(assuming the matrices have already been created for the `CameraView` and the `CameraProjection`)

```
World = XMMatrixIdentity();                             

WVP = World * CameraView * CameraProjection;

XMMatrixTranspose(WVP)
```

So my question is, what is the purpose of getting the transpose of `WVP`?  what purpose does that serve for Direct3D 11?

Comment: Surely it depends on what you're going to actually **do** with the matrix?

Comment: Well, let's say i just want to create a 3d scene with the camera and the projection in it. If i transpose the transformed matrix, what will that do?

Comment: No, but specifically what mathematical operation do you intend to with `WVP`?  Transposing doesn't really do anything; it just replaces pre-multiplication of column vectors with post-multiplication of row vectors (and vice versa).  Without context, that's about all that can be said ;)

Comment: The pattern is that the transpose happens just before setting it into a Constant Buffer which is sent to an HLSL shader... It is in fact to make the *row-major* matrix into a *column-major* matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's see how matrices can be represented in memory. Consider the following matrix.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

All values stored in computer memory are stored sequentially, there is no concept of "row" and "column", only *address*. If you represent the matrix above in *row-major order*, the float values in the matrix will be stored linearly in memory like this:

Lowest address [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ] Highest address

If, on the other hand, you represent this same matrix in *column-major order*, the float values in the matrix will be stored in memory like this:

Lowest address [ 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9 ] Highest address

So in **row**-major order, consecutive values of **rows** are contiguous in memory, whereas in **column**-major order, consecutive values of **columns** are contiguous in memory.

<s>Now, HLSL requires your matrices to be supplied in column-major order, but DirectXMath stores its matrices in row-major order because its implementation is faster that way, so you have to transpose it so that it gets fed into HLSL shaders in column-major order.</s>

**Correction:**

HLSL defaults to taking your matrices in column-major order, but DirectXMath stores its matrices in row-major order because its implementation is faster that way, so one solution is to transpose the matrices so that they get fed into HLSL shaders in column-major order. Alternatively, you can override this default so that HLSL takes your matrices in row-major order, and then you wouldn't have to transpose them.

Comment: `HLSL requires your matrices to be supplied in column-major order` ah thank you very much, this explains everything for me now :)

Comment: HLSL doesn't require it, it just *defaults* to column-major. This is covered explicitly in the DirectXMath Programmer's Guide in the **Working with D3DXMath** section under _Using DirectXMath with Direct3D_ and a link to the related [HLSL docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634.aspx#Matrix_Ordering). **In short**: DirectXMath supports either left- or right-handed viewing coordinates, but all matrices are **row-major**. You can tell HLSL to use row-major, but it defaults to **column-major** which is slightly faster. Hence the _transpose_ just before setting a CB.

Comment: To make this more explicit, I've added this topic to the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) docs on the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) GitHub wiki.